# Overlay branches in Git (Perforce)

Tags: git, perforce

I have been working with perforce for some time. We used overlay branches for customers. Only some files are specific for the customer. All other files are standard.
The overlay branch compared to a full branch has the advantage that nobody is tempted to do developments in the customer branch which should be done in the standard branch.

If a full branch would be created I would fear, that the developer would do the development in the customer branch.

Additionally with the overlay branch it is not needed to update the customer branch, if only standard things are adapted.

Is there a best practice how one can have a customer branch in which are only few adaptions?

Comment: This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: Branches are much cheaper in git than in Perforce, so you don't have to have special "types" of branches in which only a portion of the repository is branched. You can have a vast number of git branches, all of which branch the entire repository, without encountering resource consumption problems with those branches.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if developer are working in the wrong branch as long as they are not able to push into said branch. And all major Git repos hosting servers have branch protection in place ([GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/), [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/protected_branches.html), [BitBucket](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/), ...)

The developer can create his/her own branch from the customer one in order to modify only a few files in isolation.

Client specific files are best managed with a different name, and used at deployment time.